# DoctrineCacheBundle using redis Supress Errors ifcannot connect

Tags: php, symfony, redis

When for some reason the `DoctrineCacheBundle` cannot connect into redis (for example redis server has been terminated) server I need to somehow supress the `ContextErrorException` that gets thrown:

> Redis server went away

The use case is the following: I use an API to fetch some data and cache them into redis using `DoctrineCacheBundle`.

But if the redis is down then I want to skip the caching and move on into fetching from the api the data.

A sample code that explains what I want to do:

```
use Doctrine\Common\Cache\Cache as RedisClient;

class DataFetchingStrategy 
{

  private $redisClient=null;

  public function __construct(RedisClient $redisClient)
  {
      $this->redisClient=$redisClient;
  }

  public function get($item)
  {
    try {
      if($this->redisClient->contains($item)) {
        return $this->redisClient->fetch($item);
      }
    } catch(\Exception $e) {
      //Log the error here but do not break
    }

    return $this->callApi($item);
  }

  private function callApi(item)
  {
    //API Call stuff here
  }
}
```

Do you have any Idea how I will supress the error that occurs when I connect via redis and make by force to perform thew api call?

## Edit 1:

Further investigation has proved that when I try to retrieve from the controller the `DataFetchingStrategy` with the redis server down (on a local development machine) for example:

```
class MyController extends Controller
{
  public function someThingAction()
  {
    $dataFetchingStrategy=$this->get(DataFetchingStrategy:class)//Here I get the problem
    //Render view
  }

}
```

I get a `RedisException` with message

> Redis server went away

Also my problem is somehow not to get an exception when my redis server is down but to continue to fetch from the API like as nothing has happened.

Comment: What, specifically, isn't working? Your `DataFetchingStrategy` seems like it would work.

Comment: I get a `RedisException` when redis server is down and I want somehow to supress it and continue fetching from the API.